# highlighting of zsh correction

Tags: zsh, highlighting, autocorrection

When zsh's autocorrection suggests a change in long filename, it may be hard to spot which change is actually suggested:
[image: artificial example]

The example is of cause artificial as tab completion would've done the job (and I can blindly accept the correction w/o proofreading). But there may be other cases where I really want to proofread the suggestion and would appreciate if the suggested change (i.e. only the added `0` in the example) was highlighted in boldface.

EDIT: It's also discussed [on zsh-workers](http://www.zsh.org/cgi-bin/mla/redirect?WORKERNUMBER=38538) and [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/issues/323)